# Clasificar elementos de una tupla dentro de una lista en base a elementos coincidentes de las tuplas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, tuplas

La verdad batallé un poco para elegir el título de la pregunta, y aún no se si es del todo descriptivo o adecuado, así que me disculpo de antemano. Básicamente el problema lo tengo resuelto:

```
SeatsC = [(1, 'LAT'), (2, 'MOD'), (1, 'BET')]

Seats = {}

for x in SeatsC:
    if x[0] in Seats:
        if len(Seats[x[0]]) == 0:
            Seats[x[0]] = []
            Seats[x[0]].append(x[1])
        else:
            Seats[x[0]].append(x[1])
    else:
        Seats[x[0]] = []
        Seats[x[0]].append(x[1])

print(Seats)
```

Esta es la salida:

```
{1: ['LAT', 'BET'], 2: ['MOD']}
```

Este código me sirve para lo que necesito, pero quisiera saber es si hay una forma más *Pythonica* de hacer eso, siento que el código es demasiado complejo y poco entendible.

En resumen tenemos una lista con elementos del tipo tupla, y estas tuplas en ocasiones van a tener coincidencias en cuanto su primer elemento, específicamente números del 1 al 5, y quiero como salida lo que ya pueden ver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar un `defaultdict` para simplificar el manejo: creas un diccionario que retorna una lista vacía cuando usas una llave inexistente:

```
from collections import defaultdict

SeatsC = [(1, 'LAT'), (2, 'MOD'), (1, 'BET')]
dic = defaultdict(list)
[dic[a].append(b) for a, b in SeatsC]
print(dic)
```

Comment: Perdona si soy demasiado puntilloso pero creo que usar una list comprehension en el modo en que lo has hecho se considera un _antipatrón_, pues no estás almacenando la lista resultante (que de todas formas estaría llena de `None`), sino que la usas sólo por sus "efectos laterales" (la alteración de `dic`). Entiendo que es para dejarlo en una sola línea, pero ya puestos, tambén es una sola línea la sentencia `for a,b in SeatsC: dic[a].append(b)` que no incurre en ese antipatrón (y evita crear la innecesaria lista de Nones)

Comment: Guao jaja que diferencia de código, gracias, funciona de 10, y gracias @abulafia por el pequeño pero importante aporte, he unido sus dos respuestas y funciona bien.

Comment: @abulafia. Prometo no hacerlo nunca más. Dejo la respuesta sin editar para no alterar el contexto.